# What is the model of my bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: Bike]

Hi, i can't figure out what the model of my bike is. I know that it's an Orbea AVANT bike, but i can't figure out which series it is.

Any help would be a appreciated thanks!

---

The frame is made of Aluminium. The fork is carbon fibre. Everything on it is original, nothing has been changed.

I got the bike from participating in a bike tour, they didn't give me any info on what model the bike was. I've asked the people that arranged the bike tour what model the bike was, but they don't seem to have any information about the bike.

This might help a bit, the shifters, front and rear Derailleur has the text shimano 105 on them.

Comment: There are obvious welding seams, so I'd say it's aluminum. What's the history of the bike, i.e. could you just ask the seller?

Comment: When did you receive the bike? That would put a cap on what model year it is. Also, knowing your location may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bike was a 2019 (which I’m assuming it isn’t) it would be an [H30](https://www.orbea.com/us-en/bicycles/road/avant/cat/avant-h30), as that’s the current model that has an aluminum frame and 105 groupset.  It’s probably either an H30 or the equivalent from 2018 or earlier.

when trying to identify a recent bike, If the manufacturers’ web site has an archive section, you can go through it looking for a match WRT frame material, colors, major components etc. I’m writing this answer in a mobile device so I can’t see if Orbea’s main site has a link to an archive section.

If you have good guesses for model and year googling for images or past reviews will often yield a hit.

Comment: Alright thank you so much!

Comment: Some manufacturers have been known to substitute components from the listed spec sheet. This is more likely to occur if the new model year has major changes and they are late in the model year. They may substitute components from the  upgraded  model. Your research may show you have mixed components from two models.

Comment: @mikes I'm also a bit suspicious that this is custom build, with some lower level components (wheels and crank in particular) than as shipped by Orbea. It's plausible that a bike store agreed to provide a prize, grabbed an unsold previous year model, swapped in some cheaper unsold components they had lying around and then conveniently neglected to advertise the exact model. It was a giveaway so it's not really fraudulent.